# MySQL: зависание при большом количестве Update'ов

Tags: веб-программирование, php, mysql

Всем привет.

Имеется написанный сторонними разработчиками сайт. В нем есть PHP скрипт. Сайт и база вертятся на арендованном сервере на OpenSUSE, c Apache и MySQL. Заведует там всем другой человек, я не очень в Линуксах, прошу прощения.

Вот в этом PHP скрипте есть вот такой кусок кода:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            if(!empty($row['prod_form_id'])){
                sqlQuery('UPDATE `book` SET `company_book_id`='.$row['book_id'].',`type`='.$row['prod_form_id'].' WHERE `isbn`="'.$row['isbn'].'"');
            }else{
                sqlQuery('UPDATE `book` SET `company_book_id`='.$row['book_id'].' WHERE `isbn`="'.$row['isbn'].'"');
            }
        }
```

Здесь &result = sqlQuery(... запрос на базе ...), он выполняется без проблем. Проблема в том, что когда этот &result достаточно большой, то скрипт останавливается, или виснет. Просто после этого куска кода не выводится следующий флаг.

Если количество записей меньше определенного порога, то все ок (точно не ясно, какого, около 30 тыщ проходит нормально, около 50 тыщ уже нет).

Таким образом, в цикле выполняется куча Update'ов. Если их больше определенного количества - все виснет. При этом нагрузка на базу мала, в top и iotop одного процента не набирает.

Вопрос: куда смотреть, куда глядеть? Может, где-то врубается что-то типа антиспама?

Comment: еще попробуйте объединять запросы, например по 100-200 update в одном, так может выполниться чуть больше запросов. А вообще не стоит так много за раз обращаться к базе, лучше делить на более мелкие части. И да, скорее всего это таймаут.

Comment: Да, об оптимизации запросов я думал, но причина должна быть не в этом. Почему не таймаут - отписал в комментарии ниже. Дело в том, что это все прекрасно работало, пока не было перенесено на новый сервер.

Comment: > Дело в том, что это все прекрасно работало, пока не было перенесено на новый сервер

т.е. отсюда вывод:

- на новом сервере какие то другие настройки;
- новый сервер работает чуть медленнее, и не успевает выполнить 50к запросов (как предыдущий)

Comment: Вот именно, могут быть другие настройки. Вообще они по возможности были перенесены со старого, но, судя по всему, что-то таки поменялось. Я и хочу понять, что именно.

Новый сервер имеет точно такую же конфигурацию по железу, как и старый, но на старом вращалась еще куча других сайтов, виндовая виртуалка и несколько веб-сервисов. Новый сервер отдан исключительно под этот сайт и эту БД. Т.о., медленнее он работать вряд ли будет.

Answer (score 1):

Первое проверьте время выполнения php кода. 
phpinfo() строка max_execution_time .
Скорее всего Апач по таймауту прибивает.
Для теста запустите выполнения к примеру 100 запросов и замеряйте время. Дальше нехитрыми математическими вычислениями сможем узнать сколько запросов получится выполнить за отведенное время max_execution_time .

Comment: Насколько я знаю, max_execution_time действителен при запуске скрипта из браузера. В моем случае все настроено несколько иначе: скрипт запускается по крону каждые пять минут, при условии установленного в БД флага запуска. Т.е. нажал кнопку на сайте - поставился флаг - в течение 5 минут крон увидит флаг - запуск скрипта по крону. Таким образом, проблема, к сожалению, не в этом.

Answer (score 0):

А вам не кажется что PHP в принципе не создан для 50т запрос к базе? Это откровенный ********м, разумеется апач или php выкинет вам таймаут, по стандарту в 30 секунд.

Comment: Кажется. Но он уже есть, и фича в том, что такая проблема возникла после переезда на новую машинку. До этого все было в порядке.

Comment: Без разницы из браузера запускается или по крону, настройки php одинаковые. Если дано жить 30 секунд, апач прибьёт выполнение и не будет смотреть кто запустил.
На новом сервере могут быть установлены стандартные настройки php.
PS. memory_limit также проверте.Может Ваш цикл кушает много памяти.